# Reboot android programatically on Android Enterprise dedicated device

Tags: android, device-admin, android-enterprise

We are migrating from the legacy Android Device Administrator to the new Android Enterprise policies, but we are facing a challenge migrating one functionality that need to reboot the android when some hardware functionality stop working (like gms/gps stuck).

We are using the `DevicePolicyManager` (`devicePolicyManager.reboot(yourAdminComponent)`) right now but I'm not sure how to migrate it to the "new" way.

I'm still learning from this new method, I've tried to find the replacement for the DevicePolicyManager but I have no success and I CAN'T root my device, so doing through `su` is not an option for me.

(There is a possibility that I completelly misunderstood the statement on this page https://developers.google.com/android/work/device-admin-deprecation and I'm trying to find the wrong answers)

Answer (score 0):

based on my experience, I can say this:

1. You or your company should have an android enterprise account, where you can access to the android enterprise [console](https://enterprise.google.com/u/0/android/experience/alreadyenrolled), in that console you can enroll your devices.
2. Then, for customizing some actions like reboot, install apps, apply policies you should read [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1).
3. If you have your own apps and you want to implement them managed configurations [this link](https://developer.android.com/work/managed-configurations) is for you.

Regards